# Adding two SparseArrays produces zeros in the reported "NonzeroValues"

Tags: sparse-arrays

When two SparseArrays are added together and new zero values are created, these new zero values are reported as "NonzeroValues".  Example, produced with Mathematica version 10.2:

```
tst = SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}] - SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}];

tst["NonzeroValues"]
{0, 0, 0}

tst["NonzeroPositions"]
{{1}, {3}, {5}}
```

It appears that SparseArrays constructed in this way can become "polluted" with lots of false non-zeros.  Is there a way to get Mathematica to **quickly** compact such a SparseArray and strip out the introduced zeros?  In my application, I produce large sparse vectors through many such additions, and I need to quickly identify the positions of nonzero entries.

Edit:
My application is similar to RowReduce.  I have a large sparse matrix of mostly zeros and ones, and I am implementing pivoting, with selection rules based on the number of nonzero elements in the rows and columns.  After a pivot, the number of nonzero elements will change for many of the rows of the matrix.  My matrices have hundreds of rows and columns, with densities of around 1%.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Re-applying `SparseArray[]` to a matrix or vector generated in this way usually restores the sparsity.

```
p = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> {1, 2, 4}, Band[{2, 1}] -> {5, -3}}, {3, 3}];
q = SparseArray[{{2, 2} -> -2, {3, 2} -> 3, {3, 1} -> -1}, {3, 3}];

r = p + q;
rs = SparseArray[r];

Complement[r["NonzeroPositions"], rs["NonzeroPositions"]]
   {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but it requires recreation of the entire SparseArray.  In my application, the number of nonzero elements is in the thousands or tens of thousands.  Perhaps Mathematica's SparseArray implementation simply does not give a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tidier way, either. In this example, of course, I could have done `r = SparseArray[p + q];` directly; I just wanted to demonstrate that the new zeroes do get recognized.

Comment: I see now that this does solve my problem in an acceptable way.  I am updating a large matrix in a row-by-row fashion, with a need for accurate zero counts after each row change.  Hence, I only need to recreate the SparseArray for the particular row I am changing, not the whole matrix.

Comment: Yes, a construction like `{SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0}], SparseArray[{0, 0, 1, 1}]}` is certainly possible. After doing your row operations, you can then apply `SparseArray[]` to the whole thing.

Comment: @J.M. Is it a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: @dcutrell "but it requires recreation of the entire SparseArray" <- What evidence do you have that this operation is inefficient?  Re-applying the `SparseArray` had is just one possible user-interface for compacting the sparse array, and it's not clear at all how this is implemented internally.  It could, in principle, be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Alexey, which one? If you're referring to the results of subtraction still being counted as nonzero entries, I'm loath to call it a bug. The case of inexact arithmetic is especially murky; for that, how does one determine the threshold for zeroing out differences that are near, but not quite zero?

Comment: @J.M. As I understand, actually both examples (in the question and your's) demonstrate **exact** arithmetic. For the inexact cases like `SparseArray[{1., 0., 1., 0., 1.}] - SparseArray[{1., 0., 1., 0., 1.}]` zero threshold would be sufficient: ``0.` `` is zero, otherwise it isn't.

Comment: @Alexey, Yes, I was just thinking of a rationale on why "fake" nonzero entries aren't automatically zeroed out in general. This is a relatively easy case, of course.

Comment: @J.M. The only rationale that come to mind is performance of finding zero positions after every modification of `SparseArray`: it would be logical to determine such things only when it is necessary, not on every stage of computation with `SparseArray`s. That is the reason for my question: is it "by design" and the user **have to apply `SparseArray`** to the final result before using things like `"NonzeroPositions"` or is it a bug? Earlier I thought that `"NonzeroPositions"` aren't stored and calculated *on the fly*.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I would like to remind that the whole `"Nonzero*"` are undocumented, thus should be immune from prosecution. :)

Comment: @SZabolcs  The operation is necessarily inefficient because afterwards there are two complete copies of the given SparseArray.  "Re-applying the SparseArray" does not change the original SparseArray.  `tst = SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}] - SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}]; newTst = SparseArray[tst];`   `tst["NonzeroValues"]  {0,0,0}` `newTst["NonzeroValues"]  {}`

Comment: @dcutrell, you can overwrite the original with the sparsified one (`tst = SparseArray[SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}] - SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}]];`), but is your memory really that taxed for you not to want to maintain two copies?

Comment: @dcutrell I still don't understand. You don't need to keep both.  You can `sa = SparseArray[sa];`, then there will only be one copy left.

Comment: @Szabolcs,   it is true that Mathematica's memory collection will reclaim the memory from the old copy if no reference to it is retained.  However, the new copy must still be constructed in the first place.  If the array is very large, this construction is not cheap.  This is also a response to J.M.

Comment: @dcutrell That's really a theory, but you have not shown any evidence for it. If you really worry about it, then you can do this: write a LibraryLink function that uses Shared passing, to ensure no copy will be made, call `MSparseArray_resetImplicitValues` on it, the return.  But once again: 1. What evidence do you have to show that this is not what happens when you do `sa = SparseArray[sa]`?  2. Are you sure that the recomputing can at all be done without a temporary internal copy? If yes, explain why. Based on my limited familiarity with the SparseArray internal structure, ...

Comment: @dcutrell ... the arrays use to store the column indices, row pointers and the explicit values will need to be reallocated anyway, as part of shortening them. So the equivalent of an temporary copy *will* happen. Low-level memory allocation functions can't usually release part of a memory block while retaining the rest.  The way to trim an array is to reallocate the memory, copy the array, release the old large one.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I agree with you.  Some temporary memory overhead will be necessary regardless of the underlying technique.  In my case, I'm able to avoid recreating the entire matrix since I can limit the changes to specific rows of the matrix, and do the SparseArray wrapper trick on just those.  There would be more overhead if I were to wrap the entire matrix in a SparseArray wrapper.  I don't know what tricks Mathematica uses internally when a row of a SparseArray matrix is replaced, but it's **slightly** better than recreating the entire matrix.  I tested this in my larger examples and...

Comment: @Szabolcs ... I observed a 10% timing improvement between wrapping only the changed rows in SparseArray, versus wrapping the entire matrix in SparseArray.  Anyway, thanks for the probing discussion.