# What would be the Mathematica equivalent of sparse in MATLAB?

Tags: sparse-arrays, matlab

The [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function in MATLAB does the following:

> `S = sparse(i,j,v)` generates a sparse matrix `S` from the triplets `i`, `j`, and `v` such that `S(i(k),j(k)) = v(k)`. The `max(i)`-by-`max(j)` output matrix has space allotted for `length(v)` nonzero elements. `sparse` adds together elements in `v` that have duplicate subscripts in `i` and `j`. If the inputs `i`, `j`, and `v` are vectors or matrices, they must have the same number of elements. Alternatively, the argument `v` and/or one of the arguments `i` or `j` can be scalars.

I would like to have a fairly equivalent function in *Mathematica*. Has anyone tried to do this beforehand?

Comment: Isn't SparseArray close enough?

Comment: I'm not sure. What questions me is the different output of the Matlab function.

Comment: The output in matlab. It's something different, perhaps because it is compressed.

Comment: I think the difference lays in the compression of the memory.

Comment: Yes I would like to compare the implementation details.

Comment: Then ask that question :) It is possible that there is someone around who knows both but this is MMA related site so you will gather more attention bringing info about Matlab side yourself. Moreover a motiviation would be good, e.g. specific example which Matlab handles way better than MMA and you want to know why.

Comment: Ok, I'll reformulate the question later. Thank you for your advices!

Comment: are you just off by the different form?  `s=SparseArray[Transpose[{i, j}] -> v]` would seem to give exactly the same result: `s[[i[[k]], j[[k]]]] == v[[k]]`

Comment: Mathematica and MATLAB use [the same type of sparse representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) for *matrices*, except Mathematica uses row-wise storage and MATLAB uses column-wise storage, just like with dense matrices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica has sparse arrays not just sparse matrices:

- ["Sparse Array"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

Here are links to some tutorials:

- ["Working with Sparse Arrays"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraSparseArrays.html),
- ["Sparse Arrays: Linear Algebra"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SparseArrays-LinearAlgebra.html).

The ability to use high-dimensional sparse array sometimes is very useful. (E.g. see ["Markov chains n-gram model implementation"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/markov-chains-n-gram-model-implementation/).)

Most competitors of *Mathematica* support only sparse matrices.

[Yifan Hu](http://yifanhu.net) and Robert Knapp were the original designers of the functionality. I mention Yifan because before moving to Wolfram Research he worked with some of the originators and creators of the sparse matrices field (like [John Reid](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/people/hsd/jkr/)).

Comment: Slightly off-topic: if memory serves, wasn't the graph-plotting stuff an outgrowth of their work on sparse matrices?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I would say so. Yifan designed and implemented `GraphPlot` and he was using it to demonstrate the origins of some of the matrices from [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/).

Comment: The original GraphPlot design, and the graph visualization stuff that was implemented at that time, is still excellent. Things added afterwards ... so-so ...

Answer (score 4):

While comparing the results of MATLAB and *Mathematica* for a little experiment the other day, I got bitten by an error, which in hindsight was because I did not pay attention to this part of the help file for MATLAB's `sparse()`:

> `sparse` adds together elements in `v` that have duplicate subscripts in `i` and `j`.

As a demonstration, here's a small MATLAB example:

```matlab
il = [1 2 2 3];
jl = [1 2 2 3];
vv = [5 1 -1 4];
full(sparse(il, jl, vv))
ans =
      5     0     0
      0     0     0
      0     0     4
```

The ostensible *Mathematica* equivalent is

```
Normal[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 5, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> -1, {3, 3} -> 4}]]
   {{5, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 4}}
```

Did you notice the difference? As previously noted, MATLAB adds up entries with the same indices, and you thus get `0` as the middle of the diagonal matrix. *Mathematica*, OTOH, retains the first one.

In fact, this behavior is controlled by the internal setting `"TreatRepeatedEntries"`:

```
SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries"]
   {"SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}}
```

(See e.g. [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164193) and [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37566), among others.)

To get behavior similar to MATLAB, we need to modify this setting. If you are wary of modifying internal settings like these, the device of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136017) can be used to localize this effect:

```
With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]}, 
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[
              SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
              Normal[SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 5, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> -1, {3, 3} -> 4}]],
              SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]
   {{5, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 4}}
```

and we now get the same result as MATLAB.

Comment: For code that relies on `"NonzeroPositions"` and the like, note in the last example, the `{2, 2}` entry is listed among the `"NonzeroPositions"`. Use `SparseArray[
 SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 5, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> -1, {3, 3} -> 4}]]` to reset.

Comment: The issue noted by Michael has also been discussed in other threads, like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97207).