# SetOptions locally?

Tags: options, scoping

Is there a way to `SetOptions` locally? For example, I have a `Module` and inside it I am doing a lot of `Plot`s with similar options. If I do a `SetOptions[Plot, ...]` inside the `Module`, the change propagates outside. I don't like this because I have other `Module`s where I am doing other plots with different options.

Is there a way to do a `SetOptions[Plot, ...]` that only affects "local" plots (say inside a `Module`, but I am open to any scoping construct)? Here `Plot` is only an example. In general I want to set options locally for any symbol.

Comment: ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plot},
 SetOptions[Plot, Frame -> True];
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
 ]`` like this?

Comment: Why not cache the list returned by `Options[Plot]`, do your custom stuff, and use `SetOptions[]` again at the end?

Comment: @Kuba, I guess ``Internal`WithLocalSettings[]`` is also a possibility.

Comment: @J.M. I just saw your comment. Yes, this is what I thought to do also. good idea :)

Comment: @J.M. Can you post an example of how to use `WithLocalSettings`?

Comment: Yet another [alternative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22702/81) is to create local option configurations. This method does not modify global state at all, even locally, but rather passes all necessary options explicitly as local rules.

Comment: Related: [(3247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3247/121),  [(20718)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20718/121),  [(22697)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22697/121),  [(38827)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38827/121)

Comment: For the plotting problem in particular, one could [define a plot theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wolfram should support an easy way to create new themes.

Comment: There is also `BlockOptions` package in the `SciDraw` toolkit.
`WithOptions[{{Plot, {Frame->True}}}, Plot[...]]` or `BlockOptions[{Plot}, SetOptions[Plot, ...]; Plot[...]]`

Answer (score 26):

**Version 12.2**

In version 12.2, use the new function `WithCleanup[]`:

```
With[{plotOptions = Options[Plot]}, 
     WithCleanup[SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Green], 
                 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -π, π}],
                 SetOptions[Plot, plotOptions]]]
```

which is a direct replacement of the older *undocumented* function described below.

---

**Older versions**

Usual caveats about using *undocumented* functions aside, here is how one might use `` Internal`WithLocalSettings[] ``:

```
With[{plotOptions = Options[Plot]}, 
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Green], 
                                Plot[Sin[x], {x, -π, π}],
                                SetOptions[Plot, plotOptions]]]
```

<strike>but I do not think this to be any better than Nasser's proposal</strike>. As can be surmised from how it was used above, you can think of the three arguments of `` Internal`WithLocalSettings[] `` as three stages: setup, body, and clean-up. Carl notes in a comment below that the advantage of using this function is that any code in the first and third arguments are uninterruptible.

A more usual case for its use would be for localizing changes to system settings that are not easily accessible to `SetOptions[]`. Using the Wizard's code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37607) as an example:

```
With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[
              SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}],
              ind = {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1},
                     {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}};
              val = {1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1};
              SparseArray[ind -> val] // Normal,
              SetSystemOptions[spopt]]]
   {{0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {6, 6, 2}}
```

(See also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586735) and [this example usage by Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25668).)

Comment: I would say using `Internal\`WithLocalSettings` is better than using `Module`, because the first and third arguments of `Internal\`WithLocalSettings` are not interruptible, and always happen. If you add a `Pause[10]` to Nasser's example and abort the computation, you will see that the `PlotStyle` remains `Green`. Also, it's convenient that the second argument is the output, so one doesn't need to store the result so that it can be returned as the output after the cleanup occurs.

Comment: "Also, it's convenient that the second argument is the output, so one doesn't need to store the result so that it can be returned as the output after the cleanup occurs." - that was certainly a convenient feature for me, but I definitely didn't know about the non-interruptibility. Thanks @Carl!

Comment: @CarlWoll Maybe for you but if it eventually break your app you can't even complain because you used undocumented function. (the point here is to push it to ``System`​`` since everyone is using it anyway).

Answer (score 17):

I have used several methods, including the ones in the other answers. I have found that the simplest method is [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/52) as it allows for temporary changes to a symbol to be made, including changes to `Options`. For example,

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plot},
  SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True];
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Obviously, this has the most utility when you are making multiple plots, but this illustrates the point.

Comment: Why don't you (not you personally ofc) document them then? Just add where it would not be a good idea to use it, if there are any problems. It is not like ``System`​`` is perfect anyway.

Comment: @Kuba not unreasonable, but not my department.

Comment: I have a particular project in which I want to change the options of a function locally in a ScheduledTaskObject without the options change altering subsequent calls in the FrontEnd.  This solution seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 12):

Just define your options as sequence held in a local variable.

```
Module[{opts = Sequence[PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]},
  Plot[Sin[2 π x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluate @ opts]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Or use a `List` instead of a `Sequence`: `opts = {PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True}`

Comment: @becko - it's shorter ... but flavor to taste.

Comment: @becko - on my system (11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)) the `Evaluate` is still needed.

Comment: If you use `With` instead of `Module`, you can eliminate the `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a simple solution. The idea is to save the `Plot` options on entry, and restore it on leaving the module to whatever it was

```
f := Module[{savedOpt = Options[Plot]},
  SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle -> Green];
  Print@Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
  SetOptions[Plot, savedOpt]
  ]
```

Now global `Plot` options are not changed. Test:

[image: Mathematica graphics]