# What is the equivalent of MATLAB's accumarray?

Tags: list-manipulation, matlab

Is there any equivalent of MATLAB's [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)?

I'm looking for an equivalent of:

```
accumarray(A(:),B(:),[],@mean)
```

where A and B are two matrix datasets.

**EDIT:**
As asked in the comment, I will provide a bit more from the MATLAB code. As far as I understood, the first matrix contains a set of radius values (all integer values), the second contains a random pattern (here 0's and 1's) like this:

```
(* A(:) *)
a = Table[Round@Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {y, -5, 5, 1.}, {x, -5, 5, 1}];
(* B(:) *)
SeedRandom[1238];
b = Table[x y, {y, RandomInteger[1, 5]}, {x, RandomInteger[1, 5]}]
```

Now `accumarray(A(:),B(:),[],@mean)` seems to virtually collect all matrix elements of $b$ where the elements $a_{ij}$ share the same value and than the function `@mean` is applied to all those virtually collected values. After this the obtained values are written in a `List` containing `{Value of a, mean of all values of b}`. I think this is what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Any $n \times m$ Matrix, Input as well as output.

Comment: You might want to link to the MATLAB docs the next time you ask questions like these.

Comment: Why do I receive often a down vote? I think the question is somewhat clearly asked. Isn't it?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for editing. However, this would imply, that I know about this documentation link..., which I didn't knew yet.

Comment: Why the downvote? Very likely because you did not explain the problem in English.  You only explained it in MATLAB. Everyone here understands some English, but not everyone understands MATLAB.

Comment: @Kay This site is about Mathematica, information not related to it should be included or linked, that is quite obvious. Unless we talk about common knowledge, but the definition of `accumarray` does not seem to be part of it.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for your hint! I'll try to respect that for the next time!

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not an expert in MATLAB, nor in MMA, but I believe I can somewhat handle MMA. Knowing the mathmatics behind, wouldn't Need me to write this question. I get your point, but think about this: Concerning your post, another option might to ask in the Mathlab Forum. However, I think this isn't of help, as there nobody is familiar with Mathematica. But I learned, that for the next time, I'll post a link as well, to feed my question.

Comment: Kay, could you add an example of input and desired output, and an explanation of what the command should accomplish?  That would be much easier to match to an appropriate Mathematica function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. All you need to do is explain what you want to do in plain English, and not rely on a piece of MATLAB. The question should be understandable even if that MATLAB code is removed. Or are you saying that you do not fully understand what `accumarray(A(:),B(:),[],@mean)` does?

Comment: The latter is the case. Trying to match your Explanation, I would say the problem is two-fold. I do not understand the code AND I would like to have an equivalent solution for this in MMA-language. You are right, I should point this out in the question...

Comment: @MarcoB I will copy the whole MATHLAB code for this. Give me a couple of seconds.

Comment: @Kay actually, I doubt that MORE matlab code would help. I was hoping you could show us a simple example of the inputs you would give to this function in Mathematica notation, and the output you desire, also in Mathematica notation, together with a description in English of the operation you want to carry out. If you don't understand what that piece of code does, you might go ask about that on a MATLAB forum first.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @MarcoB Okay, I think I figured out, what the code is supposed to do. See the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 SeedRandom[1238];
 n = 10;
 m = 100;
 f = Mean;
 a = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {m, 2}];
 b = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {m}];
```

The first application of `accumarray` that came to my mind is the assembly of `SparseArrays`. This can be directly done with

```
sparseresult = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> f@*List}],
   SparseArray[a -> b],
   SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
  ];
sparseresult["NonzeroValues"]
```

A more flexible (but not as efficient way) to do it is by using `GrouBy` as follows

```
groupbyresult = Map[
  f,
  GroupBy[Transpose[{a, b}], First -> Last]
  ]
```

An alternative way can be obtained with `Merge`

```
mergeresult = Merge[
  Association /@ Thread[Rule[a, b]],
  f
  ]
```

Note that the ordering of the resulting array is not uniquely defined. Hence, using `Associations` is a robust way to represent it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Flatten@b` in `groupbyresult`? `b` already has a flattened form?!

Comment: None. I removed it.

Comment: For safety, one might consider using ``Internal`WithLocalSettings[]`` (see e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136017)) when playing around with `SetSystemOptions[]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the hint! I have incorporated it into the answer and also into my own utility package.

Comment: Probably the only thing I would have done differently would be to put in `sparseresult = SparseArray[a -> b]; sparseresult["NonzeroValues"]` (or even `SparseArray[a -> b] @ "NonzeroValues"` if you like things terse) as the second argument to ``Internal`WithLocalSettings[]``; as mentioned in the answer I linked to, whatever is in the second argument is automatically returned. But, your way works too.

Comment: Shorter: `Merge[Mean]@Thread[a -> b]`