# What are valid settings for the TreatRepeatedEntries sparse array option?

Tags: undocumented, sparse-arrays

There is a system option that controls how to build sparse arrays when a position is assigned more than one value.  The default setting is `First`, meaning that all remaining positions are discarded.

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First]

SparseArray[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} -> {2, 3, 4}] // Normal
(* {{0, 2}, {0, 4}} *)
```

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total]

SparseArray[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} -> {2, 3, 4}] // Normal
(* {{0, 5}, {0, 4}} *)
```

**What is the *complete* list of valid values?**

One may naïvely think that the value should be a function that will be applied to the list of values, such as `First` or `Total` (both of which work). But this isn't quite the case, as `Mean` fails.  We must use `Mean[{##}]&` instead.  Some numerical values like `0`, `1` or `2` also work.

I am implementing a function which has a *combiner function* argument which basically does the same thing as `TreatRepeatedEntries`, and I would like to dispatch to `TreatRepeatedEntries` for performance reasons. I am not fully comfortable doing this because I do not have a full understanding of which values are allowed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The complete list is (V11.2)

1. `First` or symbolic 0
2. `Total` or symbolic 1
3. `List` or symbolic 2
4. Anything else

For anything else:

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Blah];
SparseArray[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} -> {2, 3, 4}] // Normal

{{0, Blah[2, 3]}, {0, 4}}
```

The reason these are undocumented is that it is not clear how these should interact with pattern sparse arrays. To be specific this is inconsistent:

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> List];
SparseArray[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} -> {1, 2, 3}] // Normal
SparseArray[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}} -> {_, _, _}] // Normal
{{0, {1, 2}}, {0, 3}}
{{0, _}, {0, _}}
```

Another issue is that it does not work with Banded:

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {1, 1} -> 1}, {3, 3}] // Normal
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

which probably should return

```
{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: You worked a lot with LibraryLink. [Is it at all reasonable to use Shared passing and modify the pass-in arguments as a way to return multiple results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164566/12)  It seems like a dangerous thing to do. So many things can go wrong. It is not clear if this is one of the intended uses of Shared passing. There is a similar example for MSparseArray in the LibraryLink examples directory, but I haven't found such a use of MTensors.

Comment: @Szabolcs, my understanding of shared is to save the memory of duplicating the tensor.

Comment: `"Constant"` passing also avoids duplicating the tensor. I assumed that the main difference between `"Constant"` and `"Shared"` was that the latter allowed modifications (and of course also that the tensor wouldn't be freed by the kernel until the library disowns it).  But using in-place modification for returning values seems to require such great care that I am not at all confident using it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, the details of all this seem hidden behind the haze of past times. I am not sure I remember enough details to give sound advice here. Sorry.

Comment: @user21, I want the mean of repeated entries but that is not working as Szabolcs found. Any idea how to get it?

Comment: @S.B.MD.KhajaMoinuddin, `"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> (Mean[{##}] &)` works just fine.