# Multiplying two complex SparseArray objects, yielding empty SparseArray crashes kernel

Tags: matrix, bugs, complex, sparse-arrays, crash

## Problem:

When I multiply together two sparse matrices that should give back the 0 matrix, where at least one element among the two is complex and at least one is not an exact number, the kernel crashes unexpectedly with no messages generated.

4 workarounds are given at the bottom.

## Minimal working example:

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0}]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2 (* Crashes kernel with no messages generated *)
```

Note that at least one element must be complex, at least one must not be an exact number and the final result must have no non-zero elements.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Even better, anyone have a workaround? This problem shows up for me deep inside a complex differential equation of $64\times64$ *very* sparse matrices. Using non-sparse operations gives a $\sim 20$x slowdown.

I'll report to Wolfram as well, thanks!

## System:

Version: 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019). See comments for some other systems affected by this.

## Workarounds:

For those who stumble upon this in the future:

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[SetPrecision[{1., 0}, $MachinePrecision]]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2
```

Gives the desired result of an empty SparseArray. Other workarounds include:

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0}]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2
```

Avoids the crash but gives 2 "specified elements" in the result so it's less sparse than desired.

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0} + $MinMachineNumber]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2
```

Also avoids the crash but does give 1 non-zero element in the result so is technically wrong, albeit by the tiniest possible amount.

```
test1 = DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0}, 0, 2, SparseArray]; 
test2 = DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}, 0, 2, SparseArray];
test1.test2
```

Also avoids the crash and also gives 2 "specified elements" in the result.

Comment: It also crashes for me on Windows 10 v12.1.

Comment: macos version 12.0 crashes, too. Weird.

Comment: Please report this to support.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher reported!

Comment: If you're using `DiagonalMatrix[]`, perhaps just have it generate a `SparseArray[]` directly: `test1 = DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0}, 0, 2, SparseArray]; test2 = DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}, 0, 2, SparseArray];`.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties this is very interesting. Mathematica highlights `SparseArray` in red and warns "Too many arguments given for DiagonalMatrix". And yet it still runs fine. However the result is a sparse matrix with 2 elements specified when it really should be 0. But then again so does the accepted answer. Thanks for responding!

Comment: "the result is a sparse matrix with 2 elements specified when it really should be 0." - yes, that's [known behavior](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97207).

Comment: I'll ensure this is reported internally.

Comment: @J.M. thanks for sharing! Somehow this solution gives back a truly empty `SpareArray`. `test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[SetPrecision[{1., 0},$MachinePrecision]]];test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]];test1.test2`. Makes sense adding or subtracting would produce those results since adding or subtracting doesn't mix indices but matrix multiplication does. Either way thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seemed to work for me...

```
test1 = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[{1. + 0. I, 0. I}]];
test2 = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[{0. I, 1. I}]];
test1.test2
```

Comment: This is better. It still works for me even if I leave the exact `{1., 0}` and `{0, I}` in place.

Answer (score 4):

Using `N[...]` didn't work for me either. If you can tolerate the really tiny error on the order of $10^{-308}$ then here's a workaround which adds the `$MinMachineNumber` to the first matrix elements:

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{1., 0} + $MinMachineNumber]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, and returns an empty `SparseArray` as desired

```
test1 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[SetPrecision[{1., 0}, $MachinePrecision]]]
test2 = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[{0, I}]]
test1.test2
```